# Are string literals guranteed to be adjacent to each other in memory?

Tags: c

Is it guranteed that the string literals are stored adjacent in the memory?

Therefore does the below necessarily get an output `hellohello`

```
printf(3 + "%d");
printf("hello");
```

Comment: The first statement is undefined behavior, so you're guaranteed nothing.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, almost nothing is guaranteed in C and if it looks evil then it is probably undefined behaviour.

Comment: There's lots of things guaranteed in C, @missingno. That's the whole meaning of the Standard ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, string literals are stored wherever your compiler fancies. The fact that you declared two of them in consecutive lines is irrelevant. You can make no assumptions about where the compiler will store them.

The compiler can do all sorts of things. For example, if you write the following code

```
printf("hello");
printf("hello");
```

then the compiler is perfectly at liberty to create only a single literal. Or not.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, and the help. Anything about this from the C standards ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at when you refer to the standards.